# How can I express controlled unitary operation in QPE of this implementation of HHL?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, quantum-gate, qiskit, hhl-algorithm

I have found [this](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-tutorials/blob/3d6faa5979a82375f7926de67853bc382c8b2c2f/community/awards/teach_me_qiskit_2018/quantum_machine_learning/2_HHL/Quantum%20Algorithm%20for%20Linear%20System%20of%20Equations.ipynb) implementation of HHL, and I don't understand why the controlled unitary operation is expressed in the form of $\exp(i t_0 A/2)$ and $\exp(i t_0 A/4)$.

The rotation of $\pi$ and $\pi/2$ are derived by the use of $\exp(i t_0 A/2)$ and $\exp(i t_0 A/4)$,  in particular using the diagonal matrix which contains the eigenvalues. But usually, the controlled operations of QPE step is done using the matrices $A^{2^0}, A^{2^1}, … ,  A^{2^k}$. Where am I wrong?

I have also another question about the representation of the unitary operation: we can we express the unitary operation using only the matrix of the eigenvalues because $b$ is expressed on the same (standard) basis of the eigenvectors, is that correct?

Comment: Hi glS, sorry there were a few typos, I edited the question.